# Understanding dependancy objects

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm totally lost with dependancy objects and binding. I often get things working without understanding why and how, this question is about knowing what should be happening.

I have a tiny user control with the following XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

My code behind has the following

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Image), typeof(MenuItem));

    public Image Icon
    {
        get { return (Image)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(String), typeof(MenuItem));


    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
```

My MainWindow is empty, other than a reference to this control and to the ResourceDictionary. In the MainWindow code behind, I set the DataContext in the constructor.

```
   <Window x:Class="AppUi.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:AppUi.Control"
    Title="">
     //set up to Resource Dictionary - all binding and styling works fine :)
    <loc:MenuItem Icon="{Binding MailIcon}" Title="{Binding MailTitle}"></loc:MenuItem>
```

In the ModelView for the MainWindow, I have the following 2 properties

```
    private Image_mailIcon;
    public Image MailIcon{
          //inotifyproperty implementation 
    }

    private string _mailTitle;
    public string MailTitle{
          //inotifyproperty implementation 
    }
```

My question is, in the UserControl, how do I do the binding? Since it's a user control within a MainWindow, and the MainWindow already has a datacontext, I think the UserControl will inherit the DataContext from the parent (From what I have read).

So, in my UserControl XAML, should I be binding to the MainWindow's Code Behind properties OR to the ViewModel properties?

In other words, should my UserControl be

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding MailIcon}"></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MailTitle}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

OR

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Or, because I'm using a DataContext and the UserControl inherits, do I even need the Dependancy Properties at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't want to overwrite `DataContext` passed through visual tree so you can use either `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding inside `UserControl` to change binding context. The easiest way to achive this is give `UserControl` some name and use it `ElementName` binding

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="myUserControl">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon, ElementName=myUserControl}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=myUserControl}"/>
    </Grid>
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

This way binding is `DataContext` independent. You can also create `UserControl` with assumption it will always work with only specific type of `DataContext` and then you just use `Path` from that view model type but then `DataContext` of that `UserControl` must always be of the view model it's designed for (mostly inherited through visual tree)

```
<UserControl ...>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding MailIcon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MailTitle}"/>
    </Grid>
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

I would also change type of `Icon` property from `Image` to `ImageSource` for example. You already have `Image` control inside your `UserControl` and you just want to bind its `Source`

Comment: It depends on your approach. Check update on my answer. You can make control which displays some text and some icon or you can make control that displays specific `ViewmModel.MailIcon` and `ViewmModel.MailTitle`

Comment: I'm so sorry I can't give more than +1 and marked as answer... This is amazing because it means (if I've undestood) I can take the UserControl out of this project and dump it in something else! Since it's only looking at it's own DataContext (or it's own visual tree)

Answer (score 1):

> in the UserControl, how do I do the binding? ... the UserControl will inherit the DataContext from the parent

That is correct, the `UserControl` will inherit the `DataContext` from the parent `Window`. Therefore you *can* data bind from the `UserControl` directly to the parent `Window.DataContext`. Please note that you would bind to whatever object has been set as the `DataContext`, regardless of whether that was the code behind or a separate view model class.

However, you don't *have* to data bind to the parent's `DataContext` object in this situation... you have other options. You *could* data bind to your own `UserControl DependencyProperty`s using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
```

You could also name your `UserControl` and reference its properties like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=YourUserControlName}" />
```

While this example seems to be more concise, don't overlook the first example, as `RelativeSource` is a useful and powerful friend to have.

> should I be binding to the MainWindow's Code Behind properties OR to the ViewModel properties?

That's your choice... what do you want or need to data bind to? you just need to know that a direct data binding will use the auto set `DataContext` value, so if you don't want to use that, then you can just specify a different data source for the `Binding` as shown above.

Finally, regarding the need to use `DependencyProperty`s... you only need to declare them *if you are developing a `UserControl` that needs to provide data binding abilities*.